# Unexpected NULL while concatenating 2 strings using cat()

Tags: r

```
t1 <- c('064359208644', '108595042227', '115705579765', '139254098290', '163646243244')
t2 <- c('064359208644', '139254098290', '163646243244')

missing_elem <- as.character(setdiff(t1, t2))
missing_elem

if(length(missing_elem) != 0){
  ss <- cat("Missing ids:", missing_elem)
}else{
  ss <- "There are no missing ids"
}

ss
```

When I print the output of ss here it shows `NULL` but if t1 and t2 are the same and `length(missing_elem)` is 0 then ss is properly set to "There are no missing ids" and shows accordingly. Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `cat` does not return concatenated strings, but rather prints to standard output and returns `NULL` (which is why the value of `ss` is `NULL`). You likely want to use `paste`:

```
if(length(missing_elem) != 0){
  ss <- paste("Missing ids:", paste(missing_elem, collapse = ', '))
}else{
  ss <- "There are no missing ids"
}

> ss
[1] "Missing ids: 108595042227, 115705579765"
```

Comment: AAhhh!! Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get a character back, just use `paste` instead of `cat`.

Comment: Fwiw, in my own code I do `cat("Missing IDs:", paste("\t", missing_elem), sep="\n")` for this. You could add a quote from `?cat`, like "Value:
None (invisible NULL)."